# Jsf pages from entities class net beans foreign key

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Quando eu gero  o jsf pages from entities class pelo net beans, ele gera o crud de forma automatica do banco de dados até em primefaces se eu preferir, porem quando coloco alguma tabela que tem relação com chave estrangeira, na hora de fazer uma cadastro ele pega o campo desta maneira atraves de um selectOneMenu(  entities.VendaProduto[ idVenda=2 ] ), onde ele pega o caminho + o id do campo, e atribui o id e faz o cadastro de acordo com o id, quero fazer para ele pegue o nome do campo e inserir o id, ou seja no selectOneMenu vai ser  apresentado o nome quando selectionar vai cadastrar o id daquele nome.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="idUsu" value="#{vendaProdutoController.selected.idUsu}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                       var="idUsuItem"
                                       itemValue="#{idUsuItem}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, onde ele acessa o seguinte caminho vendaProdutoController.selected.idProduto.nomeProduto, que na minha logica pegava o nome do produto porem no selectOne aparece vazio.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="idUsu" value="#{vendaProdutoController.selected.idUsu}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{vendaProdutoController.selected.idProduto.nomeProduto}"
                                       var="idUsuItem"
                                       itemValue="#{idUsuItem}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

como faço para fazer com que no selectOneMenu apresente o nome corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o atributo do f:SelectedItems "itemLabel", nele você pode utilizar uma expressão, utilizando o var para escrever o que você quiser. Exemplo:

Vale lembrar que no seu selectOneMenu o value tem que ser do tipo do seu itemValue.

Comment: obg so foi colocar  a seguinte linha : itemLabel="#{idUsuItem.nome}", desculpe a demora do retorno estava em viajem